# How to use Type.GetTypeFromProgID() for Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition

Tags: c#

I am trying to get Type for Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition as under but result (type) is always null.

```
System.Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("VisualStudio.DTE.15.0", false);

EnvDTE.DTE dte = (EnvDTE.DTE) System.Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Comment: Version 15 has not shipped yet.  VS2015 was supposed to be version 13 but, well, you know.  Use Regedit.exe to see progids, they are directly under the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT node.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the product name is Visual Studio 2015, the version number is `14.0`. So try:

```
"VisualStudio.DTE.14.0"
```

(I do not have a chance to check Community Edition, but at least it works with my VS 2015 Professional.)

Comment: Thanks that's right and it works with "VisualStudio.DTE.14.0"